# Is there a way to grab errors for Google App Engine's getImageServingUrl?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

This a php application running on Google App Engine. I'm using getImageServingUrl to get a url and store it for later use. I've actually implemented this in another part of the application, but in this case, when run, the php code stops right at the point where I make the call to get the url. The are no errors in the page or in the App Engine log. Is there another place to get errors? I'm not having luck tracking down the issue. Here's what I have:

```
// At the top of the page I call this
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

// Some processing takes place to get the storage location of the image then
if (is_file($full_path_photo)) {

  echo 'Getting URL...<br>';
  $object_public_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($full_path_photo, ['secure_url' => true]);
  echo 'Successful<br>';
};

// I've also tried it like this:
$object_public_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($full_path_photo);

// And adding this before the call:
CloudStorageTools::deleteImageServingUrl($full_path_photo);
```

When I run this, I get the "Getting URL...", then nothing. The page just stops executing.

Comment: You should try-catch your code to see if any exception is throwed.
Following the doc, it may throw a \InvalidArgumentException or a \google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageException

Comment: I was thinking that somewhere in the last four hours I had tried that, but doing it this time did produce a result - "Unspecified error with image". The error is kind of a let down, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch was able to get an error message for this one. In my case it was kind of a generic error. For the overall issue I think has something to do with my buckets. I tried the whole thing with a different bucket and it seems to work. Here is the example -

```
// At the top of the page I call this
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

// Some processing takes place to get the storage location of the image in GCP storage then
if (is_file($full_path_photo)) {

try {

  $object_public_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($full_path_photo, ['secure_url' => true]);
  throw new Exception();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage().'<br>';
};
```

Thanks for the help Tom.